# Example showing $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} xf(x) \neq x_0\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, examples-counterexamples, continuity

I can looking for a simple example to illustrate $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} xf(x) \neq x_0 \lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$

For example I have tried $f(x) = x-1, x_0 = 1$ hoping that I would get a zero on one side and a non-zero on the other, but so far without success.

Can someone provide an example to this statement?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} x\frac{1}{x}$, but if you insist that $\lim_{x \to x_o} f(x)$ needs to always be defined, then such an example doesn't exist

Comment: Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $x_0 = 0$.  Then $$\lim_{x\to x_0} x f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} 1 = 1, $$ but $x_0 \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** If $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists then by the product rule for limits
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}xf(x)
=\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}x\right)\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\right)
=x_0\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x),$$
so you want to find some function $f$ and some point $x_0$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Existence of the limit is enough for the product rule; continuity is not required.

Comment: @Y.Forman I've adjusted my answer accordingly. It seems our answers have converged.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac1x$, $x_0=0$, then on the LHS we have $1$.

On the right hand side $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

How about $x_0 = 0$, $f(x) = 1/x^2$?

Answer (score 1):

If both limits exist, the equality is true by the product rule of limits: $\lim_{x\to x_0} xf(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} x \lim _{x\to x_0}f(x) = x_0 \lim _{x\to x_0}f(x)$

So the only counterexamples to equality would be cases one limit doesn't exist, e.g., $f(x)=\frac1x$ with $x_0=0$